# restricting a class method overridden by few child classes

Tags: java

I have a 1 Question asked in 1 Interview

```
class Birds {
     public void fly();
     public void eat();
     public void sleep();
}

Have several other classes extending it like -

Sparrow extends Birds{
   overriding fly();// Sparrow can have its own style to fly
   overriding eat();
   overriding sleep();
}

Eagle extends Birds{
   overriding fly();// Eagle can have its own style to fly

}

Ostrich extends Birds {
    overriding fly();// Ostrich could not fly !!!
}
```

How can I restrict such situation ?? Since parent class doesn't aware of its Child class here.
Birds class is extended by several classes some could override Some could not be able to override.

Comment: Consider the strategy factory pattern "http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html"

Comment: If you declare a method as 'final', no class can override it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use *composition*:

1. Define an `interface` called, say, `Flyable` which has a `fly()` method. `Sparrow` and `Eagle` *implement* that interface. `Ostrich` does not.
2. Define an interface called `Living`, say which has `eat()` and `sleep()` methods. All your types *implement* that interface.
3. You could point out to your interviewer that you could then have an `Aeroplane()` object that implements `Flyable` but *not* `Living`.

Comment: Same was my answer use Interface, but Interviewer asked "Answer using Classes only ,Interface is fine that way u could do what u could do for classes ??" 


so there is know other way out right ?

Comment: You could use abstract classes and `final`. But it's not quite so nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add **FlyingBird** and **GroundBird** classes and make them abstract.

```
public class Birds {
    public void eat() {
        // default implementation
    }
    public void sleep() {
        // default implementation
    }
}

abstract class FlyingBird extends Birds {
    public abstract void fly();
}

abstract class GroundBird extends Birds {
    public abstract void walk();
}

class Sparrow extends FlyingBird {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        // different implementation
    }
    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        // different implementation
    }
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        // some impl
    }
}

class Eagle extends FlyingBird {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        // some impl
    }
}

class Ostrich extends GroundBird {
    @Override
    public void walk() {
        // walk implementation
    }
}
```